# Use Array with a hash item

Tags: ruby

I have a Hash:

```
h = {a: 1, b: 2}
```

To use

```
a = Array(h)
```

What I expected is that `a` is an array and `h` is an item of `a`: `[{a:1,b:2}]`

But `a` is actually `[[:a, 1], [:b, 2]]`.

Question is, how to get my expected `a` with `Array()`?

Comment: The reason you get `[[:a, 1], [:b, 2]]` is because your code is actually trying to *convert* the hash into an Array. Not wrap it.

Comment: Also, Array() return parameter without changing when that is the array: Array([h]) will be same as [h]

Answer (score 6):

I would do

```
a = [h]
```

But if you insist on using `Array`, then you can do this (with Rails/ActiveSupport):

```
a = Array.wrap(h)
```

---

As mentioned by Tom Lord in comments, you are getting the result you're getting because `Array()` (and its brethren, like `Integer()`) are **conversion functions**. They take the input and attempt to transform it into the desired type. And you want something else.

Comment: `Array.wrap(h)` won't support in plain ruby, it is support in `ActiveSupport`

Comment: @GaganGami: oh right, thanks. BTW I do have a vanilla way too.

Comment: It might be worth noting that `Array.wrap(obj)` does much more than `[obj]` – see the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-c-wrap).

Comment: @Stefan much more might be an overstatement it is essentially `obj.respond_to?(:to_ary) ? obj.to_ary : [obj].compact`

Answer (score 0):

```
h = {a: 1, b: 2}
a = []

a.push h
```

or

```
a<<h
```

output

```
p a
[{:a=>1, :b=>2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *moustache* syntax:

```
Array.new(1) {{ a: 1, b: 2 }}
#⇒ [{:a=>1, :b=>2}]
```